# Projections from endomorphism algebra of $G$-equivariant maps

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, projection, ring-isomorphism

Let $(V,\rho)$ be a representation of finite group $G$. $V$ can be decomposed to the direct sum of isotypic components $$V \cong V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_m,$$
where, for each $i$, $V_i$ is $d_i$ copy of one irreducible representation of $G$ ($V_i=W_i^{d_i}$).
Suppose the character of $W_i$ is denoted by $\chi_i$. Then $$p_i=\frac{\dim(W_i)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \chi_i^*(g)\rho_g: V \to V$$
is a projection of $V$ onto $V_i$.

Now, I am looking for the projection of $\text{End}_G(V)$ onto $\text{End}_G(V_i)$.

So far, I know $$\text{End}_G(V)\cong \bigoplus_i \text{End}_G(V_i).$$

I also consider $\pi_i$ and $\eta_i$ to be the natural projection and injection between $V$ and $V_i$. Then $p_i=\eta_i \circ \pi_i$, and, for every $\tau \in \text{End}_G(V)$, $$\tau \mapsto \pi_i \tau \eta_i$$
is a mapping from $\text{End}_G(V)$ to $\text{End}_G(V_i)$, but it seems this map is not a ring isomorphism (or is it?)

So would you help me find a projection from $\text{End}_G(V)$ to $\text{End}_G(V_i)$ based on $p_i$?

Comment: What you have *is* an algebra homomorphism.

Comment: Would you show that? I cannot show $\pi_i \tau_1 \tau_2 \eta_i=\pi_i \tau_1 \eta_i \pi_i \tau_2 \eta_i$. I only can show  $\pi_i \tau_1 1_V \tau_2 \eta_i=\pi_i \tau_1 (\bigoplus_j \pi_j \eta_j)\tau_2 \eta_i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found my answer.
Let $p_i: V \to V$ be the projection whose image is $V_i$.
Then, the mapping $\tau \mapsto p_i \tau$ is the projection from $\text{End}_G(V)$ onto $\text{End}_G(V)$ whose image is $\text{End}_G(V_i)$.

Proof:

It is obvious that the mapping is closed under addition and is idempotent. It is also closed under ring multiplication since $p_i$ are in the centre of $\text{End}_G(V)$, which, in turn, implies
$$p_i \tau_1 \tau_2 =p_i ^2\tau_1 \tau_2 =p_i \tau_1 p_i\tau_2 .$$

Answer (score 2):

More generally, let $i\colon V\hookrightarrow W$ and $p\colon W\twoheadrightarrow V$ be $G$-equivariant homomorphisms such that $p\circ i=\mathrm{id}_V$ (i.e., $p$ is a section of $i$). Then the following is a (non-unital) ring homomorphism:
$$i\circ -\circ p\colon \mathrm{End}_G(V)\to\mathrm{End}_G(W).$$
Indeed, it is clearly additive. Moreover, it is multiplicative:
$$\begin{align*}
(i\circ F\circ p)\circ (i\circ G\circ p)&=i\circ F\circ \mathrm{id}_V\circ G\circ p\\
&=i\circ F\circ G\circ p.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $i\circ F\circ p$ does not make sense, since $p: W \to V$, but $F: W \to W$.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, now it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it does not answer my question. I want projection from $\text{End}_G(W)$ onto $\text{End}_G(V)$

Comment: @khashayar That's what this answer provides you. Unfortunately, Kenta swapped the roles of $V$ and $W$ so that $V$ is the subspace of $W$ in their answer, while you have $W$ the subspace of $V$ in your question.